# Issue with BeautifulSoup and requests parses

Tags: python, parsing, python-requests, beautifulsoup

I am getting an error when trying to use BeautifulSoup and the requests module.

My code is as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    url = ('https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_total_pages(get_html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html, 'lxml')
    pages = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a', class_='pg_link')[-1].get('href')
    total_pages = pages.split('=')[2]
    return int(total_pages)

def main():
    base_url = 'https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset='`enter code here`
    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html)
    for i in range(50, total_pages, 50):
        print (i)
```

This produces the error:

```
C:\Users\PANDEMIC\Desktop\Python-Test>vkp.py Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\Desktop\Python-Test\vkp.py",
line 23, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\Desktop\Python-Test\vkp.py", line 20, in main
    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html)
File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\Desktop\Python-Test\vkp.py", line 13, in get_total_pages
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html, 'lxml')
File "C:\Users\PANDEMIC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 192, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len()
```

Comment: you forgot `()` when you execute `get_html()` in `get_total_pages( get_html() )`

Comment: def main():
 try:
  base_url = 'https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset='
  total_pages = int(get_total_pages(get_html('https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')))
  for i in range(50, total_pages, 50):
   url_gen = base_url + str(i)
   print(url_gen)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print('you are stopped script yourself')
main()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    try:
        urll = []
        base_url = 'https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset='
        total_pages = int(get_total_pages(get_html(url)))
        for i in range(0, total_pages, 50):
            url_gen = str(base_url + str(i))
            urll.append(url_gen)
            #get_page_data(url_gen)
        pool = ThreadPool(8)
        results = pool.map(get_page_data, urll)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('you are stopped script yourself')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `()` and argument when you execute `get_html()` in

```
total_pages = get_total_pages( get_html(base_url) )
```

---

**BTW:** you don't need `url` in `get_html` because it will ovewrites your argument in next calls

```
def get_html(url):
    #url = ('https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
```

or you can use default value

```
def get_html(url='https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text
```

Full version with `base_url+"0"` as argument in `get_html(base_url+"0")`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    #url = ('https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_total_pages(html):
    soup            = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pages           = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a', class_='pg_link')[-1].get('href')
    total_pages     = pages.split('=')[2]
    return int(total_pages)

def main():
    base_url = 'https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset='
    total_pages = get_total_pages(get_html(base_url+"0"))

    print(total_pages)

    for i in range(50, total_pages, 50):
        print(i)
        #print(base_url + str(i))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    url = ('https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0')
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def get_total_pages(html):

    soup            = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pages           = soup.find('div', class_='pagination').find_all('a', class_='pg_link')[-1].get('href')
    total_pages     = pages.split('=')[2]
    return int(total_pages)

def main():
    base_url = 'https://m.vk.com/bageto?act=members&offset=0'
    html = get_html(base_url)
    total_pages = get_total_pages(html)
    print(total_pages)
```

You should pass html string to BeautifulSoup, not the function.